# abstract class vs private constructor

Tags: java, abstract-class, private-constructor

I have a java class which has only **static methods and fields**, so I don't want any object to be created for that.
I can acheive this in two ways,

1. make class abstarct.
2. use private constructor.

Which of the two is better way?

Comment: You can take a look at the `java.lang.Math` class (which have only static fields and methods). They made the constructor private.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java. Make sure your class is final too.

Comment: +1 for comment, our general queries can be found in java libraries itself.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should go with `private` constructor.

If your class is abstract, it can be extended and objects can be created. As per my understanding from the question, what you want is non instantiable class.

from [Item 4 of Effective java](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec4) :

> Attempting to enforce noninstantiability by making a class abstract does not work. The class can be subclassed and the subclass instantiated. Furthermore, it misleads the user into thinking the class was designed for inheritance

Comment: The link is inaccessible, perhaps only suitable if you are a subscriber to Safari Books Online. Here is a blog on this subject though: https://medium.com/@biratkirat/learning-effective-java-item-4-4bc457fc5674